# Получение различных данных через scala slick

Tags: scala

Проблема при реализации метода, который будет выполнять запросы(select), но не известно какие поля будут возвращены.
Имеется метод:

```
def get(query: String): Future[Either[Error, Vector[Product]]] = {
   val action = sql"#$query".as[Product]
   db.run(action).map(Right(_))
}
```

где Product - родитель всех Tuple.
Проблема в том, что в зависимости от запроса будет различный Tuple(Tuple1 - Tuple22).
Получаю ошибку

```
diverging implicit expansion for type getResult[Product]
```

Все работает, если возвращать конкретный Tuple, но это мне не подходит.
Использование готовых классов не мой случай:

```
val action = sql"#$query".as[AnyCaseClass]
```

Буду благодарен любой подсказке.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользовался [вот этой ссылкой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995708/slick-plain-sql-generic-return-type). При поправил свой код:

```
val action = sql"#$query".as[Map[String, Any]](new ResultMap())
```

Вроде, все работает.